# Remove the grey border of gauges while using JQPlot

Tags: border, jqplot, gauge

I am trying to remove the grey border of gauges while using JQPlot.
With other charts I use the following code:

grid: {
    drawBorder: false,
    shadow: false,
},

However, gauges don't seem to support this functionality.  How can I remove the borders of a gauge?
Thanks in advance